# iOS 10.0 : Use of undeclared type 'CBCharacteristic'

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, ios10, cbperipheral

I am working on BLE functionality in my app. I have added CoreBluetooth framework in my project.

I have added,

```
import CoreBluetooth
```

in the starting to swift file.

Now, when i am trying to implement below delegate method,

```
func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: NSError?)
```

It gives me error that CBCharacteristic is undeclared type.

Comment: Have you added `import CoreBluetooth` to your swift file?

Comment: Yes, i have added it in my swift file and also check delegate method in framework, it is available there. I have set use legacy swift version to true in build settings because my existing code is in swift 2.3

Comment: Can you edit your question to show more code, including where you import CoreBluetooth..  The line you have looks correct

Comment: I have added framework through build phase and also import it in my swift file. When i do Cmd+click on that delegate it switch to that framework as well but when i am trying to build it is not working.

Comment: I have edited my question, you can check it.

Comment: Quick question that may be useful for later: Which version of Swift are you using? Because since there is the `error: NSError?` part, seems before 2.2 (Error management changed since).

Answer (score 0):

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate, 
 CBPeripheralDelegate{

  }
```

implement peripheral delegate 
after it can be work.